Execution reverted when calling view provider.call function
I have an error with the line of the result:
 let data: Bytes = Bytes::from(hex::decode("386c3d1a")?); // Selector pour "slot0()"

    // Appeler le contrat
    let mut tx = TypedTransaction::default();
    tx.set_to(NameOrAddress::Address(pool_address));
    tx.set_data(data);  
    let result = provider.call(&tx, None).await?;
  
   

    // Décoder les données retournées
    let sqrt_price = U256::from_big_endian(&result[0..32]); // sqrtPriceX96
    

    Ok(sqrt_price)

here is the error :
Error: JsonRpcClientError(JsonRpcError(JsonRpcError { code: -32000, message: "execution reverted", data: None }))

